# Multiple instances of SpeechSynthesisUtterance spoken text

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

**(Edited: I figured out my own much-simpler answer, posted below, in hope is will help others.)**

I am building a web page that is using speechSynthesisUntterance to read multiple instances of text strings.

This is the javascript code I am using

```js
/*
 * Check for browser support
 */
var supportMsg = document.getElementById('msg');
var supportMsg = '';
var textnumber = document.getElementById('formid');

if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
 supportMsg.innerHTML = 'Your browser <strong>supports</strong> speech synthesis.';
} else {
 supportMsg.innerHTML = 'Sorry your browser <strong>does not support</strong> speech synthesis.<br>Try this in <a href="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html">Chrome Canary</a>.';
 supportMsg.classList.add('not-supported');
}


// Get the 'speak' button
var button = document.getElementById('speak');

// Get the text input element.
var speechMsgInput = document.getElementById('speech-msg');

// Get the voice select element.
var voiceSelect = document.getElementById('voice');

// Get the attribute controls.
var volumeInput = document.getElementById('volume');
var rateInput = document.getElementById('rate');
var pitchInput = document.getElementById('pitch');


// Fetch the list of voices and populate the voice options.
function loadVoices() {
  // Fetch the available voices.
 var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  
  // Loop through each of the voices.
 voices.forEach(function(voice, i) {
    // Create a new option element.
  var option = document.createElement('option');
    
    // Set the options value and text.
  option.value = voice.name;
  option.innerHTML = voice.name;
    
    // Add the option to the voice selector.
  voiceSelect.appendChild(option);
 });
}

// Execute loadVoices.
loadVoices();

// Chrome loads voices asynchronously.
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function(e) {
  loadVoices();
};


// Create a new utterance for the specified text and add it to
// the queue.
function speak(text) {
  // Create a new instance of SpeechSynthesisUtterance.
 var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  
  // Set the text.
 msg.text = text;
  
  // Set the attributes.
 msg.volume = parseFloat(volumeInput.value);
 msg.rate = parseFloat(rateInput.value);
 msg.pitch = parseFloat(pitchInput.value);
  
  // If a voice has been selected, find the voice and set the
  // utterance instance's voice attribute.
 if (voiceSelect.value) {
  msg.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) { return voice.name == voiceSelect.value; })[0];
 }
  
  // Queue this utterance.
 window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}


// Set up an event listener for when the 'speak' button is clicked.
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 if (speechMsgInput.value.length > 0) {
  speak(speechMsgInput.value);
 }
});
```

Here is the PHP function I am using to create the input values/fields:

```html
  <input type="hidden" name="speech-msg" id="speech-msg" x-webkit-speech value="<?php echo $thetext; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="formid" id="formid" value="<?php echo $formid;?>"
  <input type="hidden" name="voice" id="voice<?php echo $formid;?>" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="volume" id="volume<?php echo $formid;?>" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="rate" id="rate<?php echo $formid;?>" value="1">
  <input type="hidden"  name="pitch" id="pitch<?php echo $formid;?>" value="1">
 <button id="speak<?php echo $formid;?>" class="small fa fa-play">&nbsp;Listen</button>
```

The $formid variable is a numeric value. Each $formid corresponds to a separate block of text that I want to be spoken on the button press.

The process works with one block of text ($formid=1), but adding a second block of text ($formid = 2) gives the error

```
TypeError: Constructor SpeechSynthesisUtterance requires 'new'
```

How would I adjust the code to allow for multiple and separate instances of spoken text blocks?

( above code based on http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-speech-synthesis-api )

Thanks (apologies for code snippet formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Own Answer:

It turns out I was trying to complicate things too much. I found a better way; it uses just the basics of the text to speech capabilities. The following code is based on this post:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function speakthis(msg) {
    var speechMessage = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(msg);
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(speechMessage);
}
</script>
<p><?php speak_button('this is button one'); ?>&nbsp;this is button 1</p>
<p><?php speak_button('this is button two'); ?>&nbsp;this is button 2</p>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
function speak_button($msg) {
    ?>
<button onclick="speakthis('<?php echo $msg; ?>')" value="Click Me">
<?php
return;
}
```

The speak_button() function creates a button that calls the speakthis() javascript. You can call the speak_button() function multiple times as needed on a page, with each button 'speaking' different text.

It uses the default voices,etc paramters of the SpeechSyntehsisUtterance . But it is good enough for my purposes, and is not 'robotic'-sounding.